# dpkg error when entering dpkg -l *.deb

Tags: dpkg

When I run dpkg - *.db from the terminal, I get errors for all packages that states that "no matching packages found", however all of the the packages are in the folder......What else should I try?

Comment: Do you mean `dpkg -l *.deb` or, as in your question `dpkg - *.db` or else the usual `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` Confirm you are in the correct directory with : `ls` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To list all .deb packages in the current directory type:

```
dpkg -l *.deb # the asterisk is interpreted as a wildcard
```

The `-l` option lists packages matching given pattern.

To install all .deb packages in the current directory type:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```